# ERROR: "Communication link failure." when I run my software on other PCs

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I have to deliver java software which includes a sql database connection. I have completed my project but I am unable to run it on different machines. It says *"Communication link failure"*. What should I do to remove this error and run this software on other PCs? By the way it runs smoothly on my PC.

I am using intelliJ and MySQL Database.

Should I first install mySQL on their computer? Can't my jar file contain all previous details of MySQL database?

Comment: Is this desktop app or website?

Answer (score -1):

Solve this problem by changing this line

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

by this line in the imports section:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Connection import;
```

I hope I have helped.